# Django: cache a dictionary containing a lambda function

Tags: python, django, django-cache

I am trying to save a dictionary that contains a lambda function in `django.core.cache`. The example below fails silently.

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set("lambda", {"name": "lambda function", "function":lambda x: x+1})

cache.get("lambda")
#None
```

I am looking for an explanation for this behaviour. Also, I would like to know if there is a workaround without using `def`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The example below fails silently.

No, it doesn't. The `cache.set()` call should give you an error like:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Why? Internally, Django is using Python's [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) library to serialize the value you are attempting to store in cache. When you want to pull it out of cache again with your `cache.get()` call, Django needs to know exactly how to reconstruct the cached value. And due to this desire not to lose information or incorrectly/improperly reconstruct a cached value, there are several [restrictions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) on what kinds of objects can be pickled. You'll note that **only** these types of functions may be pickled:

- *functions defined at the top level of a module*
- *built-in functions defined at the top level of a module*

And there is this further explanation about how pickling functions works:

> Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully qualified” name reference, not by value. This means that only the function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the function is defined in. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its function attributes are pickled. Thus the defining module must be importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised.